# How to change errors messages in Arabic language?

Tags: codeigniter

I have made site in English language and want to change in Arabic language. How I can change default error messages in Arabic. I have added Arabic language in application folder and loaded in controller.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked in to i18n? Have a quick google for "code ignitor i18n".

Comment: I have checked but not working for me. I don't want to write single messages in other language. I want to change default form validation errors to Arabic.Please let me know other way

Comment: Default error messages are in `system/language/english`. You have to copy those files into `application/language/arabic` and tranlate all in in.

Comment: I have added the same. When I have set default language Arabic in config, it showed error Unable to load the requested language file: language/arabic/ar_lang.php.

Comment: Check if file is there. Take care of case sensitivity.

Comment: In language/arabic folder, no file exist with name ar_lang.php. In English also no file with en_lang then how i can call form validation of Arabic file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a set of language files (or just one in this case) similar to those already present in *system/language/english*.

Create a folder named arabic in *system/language* (only english should be present), copy the file *form_validation_lang.php* from
the english folder into the arabic one and translate the strings (like Tpojka already suggested).

Then you'll just need to switch the "Default Language" in *application/config.php* from english to arabic.

Are you sure you changed the language in *config.php* and not in *autoload.php*?
The language feature in autoload.php seems to serve the purpose to supply additional language files relative to the language 
defined in config.php.

Be sure to not supply any values to `$autoload['language'] = array();`